# Assigning custom RGB colors to DataFrame values when plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame full of unique values. I also have a dictionary containing values in the DataFrame and their unique RGB tuple associated with each value. I am trying to plot said values based on their location within the DataFrame and assign each location to its specific color.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? For example `df.plot.scatter( color=...)`  can get list with colors for every value separatelly or column from dataframe with colors - so you can create new column in DF and assign color for every row and use this column to set color in plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to create column with color assigned to value and later you can use this column to set color in plot

```py
colors_for_values = {1:'#FF0000', 2:'#00FF00', 3:'#0000FF'}

df['Column_with_Color'] = df['Column_with_Value'].map(colors_for_values)

df.plot.scatter(..., y='Column_with_Value', c='Column_with_Color')
```

---

Minimal working code

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'A': [1,2,3,1,2,3], 
    'B': [4,5,6,4,5,6], 
    'C': [7,8,9,7,8,9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#colors = {1:'r', 2:'g', 3:'b'}
#colors = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue'}
colors_for_values = {1:'#FF0000', 2:'#00FF00', 3:'#0000FF'}

df['Color'] = df['A'].map(colors_for_values)
df['Index'] = df.index

print(df)

#df.plot.scatter(x='Index', y='A', c=['r', 'g', 'b'])
df.plot.scatter(x='Index', y='A', c='Color')

plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Instead of own colors you may also use predefined [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

random.seed(0) # to get always the same values

data = {
    'A': [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Index'] = df.index

print(df)

df.plot.scatter(x='Index', y='A', c='A', cmap='hsv', title="colormap: 'hsv'")
df.plot.scatter(x='Index', y='A', c='A', cmap='plasma', title="colormap: 'plasma'")

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

You could try to create own colormap using your values but I never tried to do this.

Comment: How would you do this for all columns in the DataFrame?

Comment: you would  need `for`-loop or .apply()` to repeate it for every column and create columns `ColorA`, `ColorB`, `ColorC`

Comment: BTW: using `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot it you coud use [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)